# VBA code works quickly and perfectly in Excel 2010, but takes 30 seconds to add one record in Excel 2016 or later

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first post to stack overflow, so please let me know if I am doing something wrong.  I am having an interesting situation where the below code works almost instantly on Windows 7 using Excel 2010 and we have had no issues with it for years, but now it takes almost 30 seconds to add a record on Windows 10 using Excel 2016 and/or Office 365. This is causing a painful delay in productivity for the user (We just switched to Windows 10/Excel 2016 this week due to Windows 7 EOL) I am wondering if perhaps I am missing something new in VBA/Excel that might be causing such a delay or if the code needs some cleaning up. Note: I did not write this code, but I am tasked with fixing it.

The code brings up a VBA userform that the user can type or copy and paste up to 16 different fields (as seen below).  Once they click the add button, it adds the record to the ws list.  Nothing complicated at all and theoretically it should run instantly.  I have no idea why it is taking so long.  Can anyone please help?

Thank you!

### CODE

**Module1**

```
Sub showme()
    frmqcinfo.Show 0
End Sub
```

**user form frmqcinfo**

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim addme As Range
    Set ws = Sheet1
    Set addme = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    If Not IsDate(txtdate.Value) Then
        MsgBox " The date field must be a proper date", vbExclamation, "Date format error"
        Me.txtdate.Value = ""
        Me.txtdate.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Me.txtqcdte.Value = "" Or Me.cboproc.Value = "" Or Me.txttdk.Value = "" Or         Me.txtsmpsz.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "There is insufficient data. All fields must be added", vbExclamation, "Mandatory                 fields are incomplete"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With ws
    'set the date format to suit your area

        addme.Value = Format(txtdate.Value, "mm/dd/yy")
        addme.Offset(0, 1).Value = Me.cboproc.Value
        addme.Offset(0, 2).Value = Format(txtqcdte.Value, "mm/dd/yy")
        addme.Offset(0, 3).Value = Format(txttdk.Value, "00")
        addme.Offset(0, 4).Value = Format(txtsmpsz.Value, "00")
        addme.Offset(0, 5).Value = Format(txttranty.Value, "00")
        addme.Offset(0, 6).Value = Format(txtmissln.Value, "00")
        addme.Offset(0, 7).Value = Format(txtmdate.Value, "00")
        addme.Offset(0, 8).Value = Format(txtcovamt.Value, "00")
        addme.Offset(0, 9).Value = Format(txtwdk.Value, "00")
        addme.Offset(0, 10).Value = Format(txtesc.Value, "00")
        addme.Offset(0, 11).Value = Format(txtcsr.Value, "00")
        addme.Offset(0, 12).Value = Format(txtwrnst.Value, "00")
        addme.Offset(0, 13).Value = Format(txtcarrier.Value, "00")
        addme.Offset(0, 14).Value = Format(txtpolnum.Value, "00")
        addme.Offset(0, 15).Value = Format(txtfldzn.Value, "00")
        addme.Offset(0, 16).Value = Format(txtodd.Value, "00")
        addme.Offset(0, 17).Value = Format(txtoth.Value, "00")

    End With
    Sheet4.Select
'reset the form
    Unload Me
    frmqcinfo.Show 0
'update the sheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You don't appear to turn `Screenupdating` off (but you should) even though you turn it back on. Also, why unload the form just to load it again?

Comment: `With ws` ... `End With` is useful only if you are using `ws` properties or methods, which is not the case here.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through to find out which bit of code takes time?

Comment: Thank you all for your comments.  I turned screenupdating off and got rid of the code that turns it back on and got rid of the unload, with ws...end with. To no avail, other than making the code simpler (Thank you!).  When I step through the program it seems to be getting hung up on the addme.Offset lines. @Zac

Comment: Try turning off calculations: `Application.Calculation = xlManual`. Then turn it back on at the end: `Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic`

Comment: @Zac, this worked!!

Comment: Glad it helped. I'll add it as an answer. Can you accept it so that this query can be closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try turning off calculations: `Application.Calculation = xlManual`. Then turn it back on at the end: `Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic`

Comment: Thanks again for the help and answer @Zac and thanks everyone else who helped me clean up unnecessary steps.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped